# Align plots with a shift

Tags: plotting, alignment

I've got three plots combined through Overlay:

```
Overlay[Table[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, ss], x], {x, -2, 2}, 
     Axes -> {True, False},
     Ticks -> None,
     PlotRange -> {All, {0, 2}}, 
     ImageSize -> 200], 
     {ss, {.2, .5, 1}}]]
```

Now I'd like to obtain something like this:
[image: overlaid plots with a shift]

I tried to achieve that with the Alignment option but to no avail. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: `Offset` might be what you need.

Comment: Is this a one-shot deal? If so, just using drawing tools to combine/align is easiest. Otherwise, `Inset` or `ImageCompose `are possibilities.

Answer (score 19):

This is the same as your code plus the horizontal lines and some formatting:

```
cornflowerBlue = RGBColor[0.392193, 0.584307, 0.929395];
plots = 
 Table[
  Show[
    Graphics[{LightGray, Thick,  Line[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], (* the line *)
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, ss], x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, cornflowerBlue]]], 
  {ss, {.2, .5, 1}}]
```

Now we translate each graphic as we assemble them:

```
Graphics@MapThread[
  Translate, 
  {First /@ plots, 
   Accumulate@ConstantArray[0.5 {1, -1}, Length[plots]] (* generate the shifts *)
  }]
```

Modify the `0.5 {1, -1}` translation vector to control the relative translation of the figures.

There are two key points:

- extracting the graphics primitives from the output of `Plot` using `First`
- using `Translate` to position them

An advantage of this method is that unlike `Overlay` it generates an actual `Graphics` object which is easier to export to the correct size.

[image]

Comment: This `cobalt` looks great but I can't reproduce it, it is significantly darker on my screen :/.

Comment: @Kuba Fixed now.  I tend to use the NamedColorsPalette[] from the [SciDraw package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/).  I *think* these may have come with some older version of Mathematica, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, it's [this one](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6812/) where the colours came from, I think the NamedColors package just added a palette to make it easy to choose a pretty one.

Comment: Indeed, thank you ;)

Answer (score 17):

Maybe not exactly what you were looking for, but this reminded me of a plotting function I made recently, so here it is.

```
data = Table[{x, 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[0, ss], x]}, {ss, {1, .5, .2}}, {x, -2, 
    2, .01}];
data2polygon[list_, offset_] := 
  Module[{forward, backward, zeros, yvalues},
   zeros = PadRight[{}, Length[list]];
   yvalues = PadRight[{}, Length[list], offset];
   forward = Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], yvalues, list[[All, 2]]}];
   backward = Transpose[{Reverse[list[[All, 1]]], yvalues, zeros}];
   Polygon[Join[forward, backward]]];
ptable = Table[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], data2polygon[data[[n]], n]}], {n, 
    Length[data]}];
Show[ptable, Boxed -> False]
```

When the result is spit out, it looks like this

[image]

But then you can change the viewing angle with your mouse and you end up with something similar to what you asked for:

[image]

And then you could take it farther to add more plots,

```
data = Table[{x, PDF[NormalDistribution[0, ss], x]}, {ss, 
    1, .1, -.1}, {x, -2, 2, .01}];
ptable = Table[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.55], Red, EdgeForm[Blue], 
     data2polygon[data[[n]], .7 n]}], {n, Length[data]}];
Show[ptable, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

edit: It would be nice to find a way to automatically label the different plots in that last image, I may try to do so sometime in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like a combination of `Inset/Offset` is the way to go:

```
plotTab = 
    Table[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, ss], x], {x, -2, 2}, 
    Axes -> {True, False}, 
    Ticks -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {All, {0, 2}}, 
    ImageSize -> 200], 
    {ss, {.2, .5, 1}}];

Graphics[Table[
    {Inset[plotTab[[ii]], Offset[{10*ii, -10*ii}, {0, 0}]]}, 
    {ii, Length[plotTab]}]]
```

[image]